# Remove warning on captcha using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, captcha, antd

I'm working on a captcha using reactjs and ant design. Its the code is working, its just there's a warning that I cant solve.

Looks like it will be a problem in the future.

Thanks,

hope you understand me.

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `u`. Keys should
>   be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.
>   Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted —
>   the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjq06nw6w1)

```
let numbers = [];
function NumberList() {
  var rand = Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substr(2, 4);
  var a = rand.split("").join(",");
  var array = a.split(",");
  numbers = array;
  const listItems = numbers.map(number => (
    <div key={number.toString()}>{number}</div>
  ));
  return <div className="randomChars">{listItems}</div>;
}

// Captcha.
class Captcha extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
  }

  fetchCaptcha() {
    let concatNumbers = numbers.join("");
    return concatNumbers;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Captcha" ref="childref">
        <NumberList />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any characters are the same the `number.toString()` will be the same, and if keys aren't unique that warning is shown,

An alternative way to make sure that keys are unique is to pass `index` in `map` function, so change:

```
const listItems = numbers.map(number => (
    <div key={number.toString()}>{number}</div>
));
```

To:

```
const listItems = numbers.map((number, index) => (
    <div key={index}>{number}</div>
));
```